# Trying to make connection to oracle 10g using plsql

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle10g

I am trying to make a simple connection to oracle db with asp .net website to populate a gridview. but error is showing like this "Additional information: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"
The same is working properly in vs 2008 but in vs 2015 it is giving error.Error appears at con.open();.Any Idea would be appreciated.
c#

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{ 
    //connection file for data base connection
    String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conndbprodnew"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OracleConnection Con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        Con.Open();
        DataTable tab = new DataTable();
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter("select * from Par_conn", Con);
        da.Fill(tab);
        GridView1.DataSource = tab;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        Con.Close();
        Con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

web config

```
 <connectionStrings>
        <add name="conndbprodnew" connectionString="Data Source=Dev;User ID=dew;Password=mes;Unicode=True" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>    
      </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Try restart current machine and re-run the project afterwards, have you get same error after restarting?

Comment: Are you using the same configuration when you run from vs2008 and vs2015? (e.g. x86/x64/Any CPU)?

Comment: no it is different

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i restar but it's not working

Comment: What happens if you use the same configuration in 2015 as in 2008?

Comment: Have you installed ODAC, ODP & ODT corresponding to machine platform (x86/x64)? If you have TNS undefined, try using data source parameters such like `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=Dev)))`.

Comment: Also it may be worth looking at the Networking Configuration with ODP.NET, Managed Driver section in [this Oracle article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-mar/o24odp-2147205.html)

Comment: Error appears at con.open() ."Additional information: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"".

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto ODAC has been installed but still exist the same error.I had referenced the Oracle.DataAccess.dll in project